# Retrofit not write all request's data

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I have a problem with retrofit.
My app have an buttom called `Request`. When user click `Request` button then retrofit executes a request.
Can you explain me why retrofit not write all data for second request?

There are retrofit config:

**Retrofit config:**

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
             .baseUrl(BuildConfig.API_BASE_URL)
             .client(client)
             .addConverterFactory(gson)
             .addCallAdapterFactory(rxAdapter)
             .build();
```

**HttpClient**

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
     logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC);
     TokenInterceptor tokenInterceptor = new TokenInterceptor();
     return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
             .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
             .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
             .addInterceptor(tokenInterceptor)
             .addInterceptor(logging)
             .cache(cache)
             .build();
```

There are http log from retrofit:

- First click, retrofit write 155088-byte body and server returns 403
- Second click, retrofit not write all data (only 2023-byte body). and client got `Unable to resolve host` error.

  > 10-30 21:01:08.858 14479-14626/com.example.retrofit D/OkHttp: --> POST
  >   https://com.example.retrofit/v1/symptom/update/257 http/1.1
  >   (155088-byte body) 10-30 21:01:09.190 14479-14626/com.example.retrofit
  >   D/OkHttp: <-- 403  https://com.example.retrofit/v1/symptom/update/257
  >   (332ms, 560-byte body) 10-30 21:01:23.109
  >   14479-14573/com.example.retrofit D/OkHttp: --> POST
  >   https://com.example.retrofit/v1/symptom/update/257 http/1.1 (2023-byte
  >   body) 10-30 21:13:27.578 14479-14573/com.example.retrofit D/OkHttp:
  >   <-- HTTP FAILED: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host
  >   "com.example.retrofit": No address associated with hostname

Answer (score 0):

The error `Unable to resolve host "com.example.retrofit": No address associated with hostname` means that either you don't have internet connection so client is not able to connect to the website, or the website itself does not exist. In your case it surely looks like there is no website called `com.example.retrofit`.

For retrofit to serve you better, it needs to connect to your host back-end website or your local host website address which goes into `.baseUrl(websiteUrl: String)` method

`BuildConfig.API_BASE_URL` is not the way to go for it.

To get you started with retrofit, you should use third party free to use APIs like [Github](https://developer.github.com/v3/), [DarkSky](https://darksky.net/dev) etc.

Follow the instructions there to use the APIs and then see the magic of [retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Comment: The device is still connected. The first time it works and the second time it not work.

Comment: `BuildConfig.API_BASE_URL` is and constant value on `build.gradle`

Comment: `com.example.retrofit` this is fake url to ask on stackoverflow.

Comment: Make sure that the second time you connect is the same website, as the error you are getting can appear in only two cases which I mentioned, no internet scenario and no website host scenario. If you say you have internet then it must be the website you are trying to ping has some issue.